# Vtiger +FreePBX : Call Status is not updated after call hang-up

Tags: java, asterisk, vtiger, freepbx, vtigercrm

I've integrated FreePBX with Vtiger (PBXManager),I've used this steps for integration https://wiki.vtiger.com/vtiger6/index.php/Asterisk_Integration

In my setup FreePBX and Vtiger both are on different server.

Calls are working fine but call status and other data is not updating in Vtiger. Even after call is hang-up its showing ringing in Call Status field and if I go to detail view its showing me recording URL as blank.

[image]

This is the log which I'm getting in `nohup.webapp.log` file

http://pastebin.com/m8ErDKt9

`VtigerAsteriskConnector.properties`

```
/*
 * Copyright (C) www.vtiger.com. All rights reserved.
 * @license Proprietary
 */

// Location where the application server will be running.
ServerIP   = 127.0.0.1
ServerPort = 8383

// Call Recordings storage path
StorageDir = /VtigerAsteriskConnector/recordings

// Enable(true) or Disable(false) call recordings
Recording = true

// Location where the applications database files will be stored.
AsteriskAppDBPath = /VtigerAsteriskConnector/db

// Asterisk Server Details
AsteriskServerPublicIP = asterisk-server-public-ip
AsteriskServerIP   = 127.0.0.1
AsteriskServerPort = 5038
AsteriskUsername   = vtiger
AsteriskPassword   = 5c11bea0b374299c2c70e09b4734a670

// Vtiger CRM URL
VtigerURL = http://vtigercrm.url.com
VtigerSecretKey = 167523039v54f1v677c2231

//Enable(true) or Disable(false) Asterisk Events and Database Logs in Connector
AsteriskLog = true
DatabaseLog = true
```

This seems related to `asterisk-java` library to me but I'm not sure,I've done same integration in one of my local VM and it works without any issue the only difference is in my local machine FreePBX and Vtiger both resides on same server.

I'll provide configuration files if anyone is needed.

Any suggestion and idea will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At current moment vtiger asterisk connector work only with asterisk 1.8

With any other version(1.4- or 11+) it not work correctly

Comment: I've just recently upgraded my FreePBX to latest version :(. I wonder why its working in my local VM where I'm having asterisk 11.21.2. However I'm upgrading it to latest to see if it works or not

Comment: No,it not working full for 11 and any recent. They not give source code of connector, so no way to fix that.

Comment: you're right , I've just downgraded to asterisk and the part which was not working started working now I mean its updating the call status. But as you're saying it's not working fully with Asterisk 11+, I'm worried about what other functionalities is broken.

Comment: Seams like vtiger developers not care much.Asterisk connector work SOMETIMES with SOME versions of vtiger and asterisk. Such situation since it invented(more then 5 years for now). Probably possible develop new connector, but that take alot of time of expert, so you have only that one now.

Comment: Also note, you need restart connector part at asterisk machine every night. Otherwise it go core dump with time(in few weeks).

Comment: Thanks a lot man for this information, you almost solved my problem, let me accept your answer but please do let me know if you find anything related to this issue.